# When is an elected moderator shown as "departed" on the election page?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election, flair

On Philosophy, one of the elected moderators has since deleted their account, and they're shown as "Departed" on [the election page](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/election):

> [image]

However, [on The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election), one of the elected moderators still has their "previous" flair shown in place, despite the fact that they've already resigned and left the Network completely in the wake of the recent events.

> [image]

[And on Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/election), the same happens (old flair remains), but without the clickable `<a>` around the image, and with a noticeable [vertical displacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WTBu.png):

> [image]

This looks inconsistent, so when exactly will a placeholder image showing "Departed" replace the flair for a departed election winner?

Comment: Is it possible the other moderators are still in the process of being removed? Accounts with that much reputation awarded are reviewed manually. If they have a lot of rep on multiple sites, that takes a while.

Comment: <has since deleted their account> maybe that's the answer you're looking for?

Answer (score 13):

The "departed" message is shown when a former elected moderator subsequently deletes their account. Since this results in a broken image being shown on the election page, staff will manually put in this placeholder image to show that there was a winner, who is no longer with the site, and to avoid the broken image icon displaying.

Stack does [not plan on supporting situations of moderators deleting their accounts](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8112/33591), however, so this is [manually done every time.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340242/broken-flair-in-election-page-due-to-moderator-having-deleted-his-account#comment1147203_340242)

> Deleted candidates is not a scenario well-supported nor one we have any intention of encouraging.
>
> I manually patched up the list of winners, which should be sufficient to indicate what happened. But we will not modify votes or alter any other data connected to the election (that is: We're not going to create fake users with fake votes winning fake positions in an old election to paper over the fact that two of the winners decided to leave; they're gone).
> -Shog9 [Feb 13, 2016](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8112/33591)

> @Mithical one-off fix. The results are actually stored as html text in a db field. Changing it programmatically is not justified at this point. To fix it, we would have to add logic to the user deletion to parse all election results for their Id and replace it with something else. Doable but not worth it right now. – Yaakov Ellis♦ [Jan 21, 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340242/broken-flair-in-election-page-due-to-moderator-having-deleted-his-account#comment1147203_340242)

Since this is done manually, this may lead to inconsistencies, such as the case on Software Engineering you noted in the question, where instead of the "departed" box it appears that someone opted to just show the latest version of the moderator's flair before their account was deleted.